# System Stored Procedure Missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, system-stored-procedures

I'm beginning in SQL Server dev. I'm working with 2 servers, one has a System Stored Procedure called "sp_send_dbmail" from the dbo schema on the System Database msdb but the second hasn't it.

When something is missing on one of theses servers, I just right click on a function/table/view then I click on "Script as ... CREATE", then I right click on the script and do Connections > Change Connections. I connect on the other server then I execute the create script to create the missing element from the first server to the second one.

But here I want to copy a System Stored Procedure, but I can't do "Script as ... CREATE" on a System Stored Procedure...

How can I do the trick ?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a system stored procedure called `sp_send_dbmail` that is installed when you configure [Database Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189635.aspx). It's possible that Database Mail has only been configured on one of the two servers you are working with.

Copying the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure to the other server will not enable Database Mail. You will need to [follow the steps to enable Database Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh245116.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! i sent it to my administrator

Answer (score 2):

```
use msdb
go
exec  sp_helptext sp_send_dbmail
```

use this statement in sql to get text of stored procedure

Comment: Thanks ! I did "Use msdb

 exec  sp_helptext sp_send_dbmail" and i get the following error : "There is no text for object 'sp_send_dbmail'."

Comment: its working on my local system. which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 10.50.1600.1

Comment: I also have the same version. It might be a permissions issue. Are you logged in with db admin user?

Comment: No i think not, all the db_* roles are uncheck on my login properties

Comment: Ask your database administrator to give you permissions to view defintions of stored procs